# Iterating over values for array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have array of hashes like:

```
AWARD = [ 
         {'KARMA_POINTS' => %w(initiate apprentice knight ace guardian sage master grand_master)},
         {'MICROBLOGS_POSTED' => %w(uno_plus)},
         {'COMMENTS_POSTED' => %w(first_responder)},
         {'IDEAS_POSTED' => %w(aryabhatta newton einstein)}
       ]
```

Need to iterate over values for a key if it matches a particular key in given hash (`AWARD`).

Any suggestion and solution will be appreciated.

Comment: I can see a hash only, what next ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I didnt get your question

Comment: What connection does `AWARD` have to the hash?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want :

```
AWARD.each do |hash|
   # I used Hash#[] method. This method will return key if found, or nil.
   # As `nil` treated as falsy in Ruby, on nil **unless** block wouldn't be executed,
   # otherwise it will.
   unless hash['match_key'].nil?
     # I am calling here `Hash#each` method.
     hash.each do |key,value|
       value.each do |elem| # as values are Array, so calling Array#each
         # your code
       end
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: `AWARD` is an `Array`, not a `Hash`

Comment: @JohnDibling Fixed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each `Hash` in the array.  For each `Hash`, iterate over each key=>value pair.  For each key=>value pair, do your thing.

```
AWARD = [ 
  {'KARMA_POINTS' => %w(initiate apprentice knight ace guardian sage master grand_master)},
  {'MICROBLOGS_POSTED' => %w(uno_plus)},
  {'COMMENTS_POSTED' => %w(first_responder)},
  {'IDEAS_POSTED' => %w(aryabhatta newton einstein)}
]

AWARD.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key,value|
    value.each do |item| 
      # your code here
      puts item 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ohh!! I messed it up..

Comment: @John Dibling Adding one more question in it, How do I represent those values of keys if I need to iterate over it. Like in array we iterate like Array[0]. Since I have to check if one value of key is there we need to award other value.